# Dynamically display array of objects

Tags: javascript, html, arrays, reactjs, jsx

Using React, I am trying to dynamically display my array of objects into a side navigation. Is there an effecient way to map and display my values cleanly? I've tried dividing tabs and title into two seperate arrays and removing the duplicates from tab. Then I was able to map and display the tabs but how would I do this for the titles? Is there an easier solution

Something like this but not hard coded in.

```
<div>Lead</div>
   <div>new lead</div>
   <div>reached out</div>
<div>Applicant</div>
   <div>new applicant</div>
   <div>recruiter screen</div>
<div>Interview</div>
   <div>exploratory chat</div>
   <div>hired</div>
```

My array of objects:

```
nav = [
    {tab: "Lead", title: "new lead"},
    {tab: "Lead", title: "reached out"},
    {tab: "Applicant", title: "new applicant"},
    {tab: "Applicant", title: "recruiter screen"},
    {tab: "Interview", title: "exploratory chat"},
    {tab: "Interview", title: "hired"},
]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you asking about how to structure your data? If so, you could create an array of objects to group them together like so:

```js
const nav = [
  { tab: "Lead", titles: [ "new lead", "reached out" ] },
  { tab: "Applicant", titles: [ "new applicant", "recruiter screen" ] },
  { tab: "Interview", titles: [ "exploratory chat", "hired" ] },
]
```

If you first need to convert the array to this data structure you would want to leverage the `Array.reduce` higher-order method.

```js
nav.reduce((accumulator, navItem) => {
  const exists = accumulator.find((existingNav) => existingNav.tab === navItem.tab)

  if (exists !== undefined) {
    exists.titles.push(navItem.title)
  } else {
    accumulator.push({ tab: navItem.tab, titles: [ navItem.title ] })
  }

  return accumulator
}, [])
```

To render this to the desired output, you could do this:

```js
nav.map((navItem) => (
  <>
    <div>{navItem.tab}</div>
    {navItem.titles.map((title) => <div>{title}</div>)}
  </>
))
```

Comment: I am asking how can I display them in divs to look like the example I gave. Structuring them in an array of objects that way might help.

Comment: @MichaelLee I updated my answer, let me know if that answers your question.

Comment: How would I transform the data I have right now, to the array of objects you gave?

Comment: I'll update the answer again to show you how you can convert your current data structure to the data structure I suggested.